# match the first & last whole word in a variable

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use php [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match/) to match the first & last word in a variable with a given first & last specific words,

example:

```
$first_word = 't'; // I want to force 'this'
$last_word = 'ne'; // I want to force 'done'
$str = 'this function can be done';

if(preg_match('/^' . $first_word . '(.*)' . $last_word .'$/' , $str))
{
     echo 'true';
}
```

But the problem is i want to force match the whole word at (starting & ending) not the first or last characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **\b** as boudary *word* limit in search:

```
$first_word = 't'; // I want to force 'this'
$last_word = 'ne'; // I want to force 'done'
$str = 'this function can be done';
if(preg_match('/^' . $first_word . '\b(.*)\b' . $last_word .'$/' , $str))
{
     echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that what i want

Answer (score 3):

I would go about this in a slightly different way:

```
$firstword = 't';
$lastword = 'ne';
$string = 'this function can be done';
$words = explode(' ', $string);
if (preg_match("/^{$firstword}/i", reset($words)) && preg_match("/{$lastword}$/i", end($words)))
{
    echo 'true';
}
```

==========================================

Here's another way to achieve the same thing

```
$firstword = 'this';
$lastword = 'done';
$string = 'this can be done';
$words = explode(' ', $string);

if (reset($words) === $firstword && end($words) === $lastword)
{
    echo 'true';
}
```

This is always going to echo true, because we know the firstword and lastword are correct, try changing them to something else and it will not echo true.

Comment: thank you for your help, but this code don't match the whole word it gives 'true', 
i want it to give true only if i passed: $firstword = 'this'; , $lastword = 'done';

Comment: well change your firstword and lastword variables to this and done respectively

Comment: I changed it but still gives 'true' in all cases.
I use this code to search and want to prevent give results except matches the whole word (not the first or end character only)

Comment: Try changing the firstword variable to 'fail' and see if it gives true

Comment: I know , I don't mean to type different word.
I want to match the whole word and don't match the characters
if you try ($firstword = 'this' or $firstword = 'th') it will give 'true' but i want it to give 'true' at the first case only (when $firstword = 'this')

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to get Start of sentence but it is not any regex in it.
You can write for end like this.  I don't add function for the end because of its long...

```
<?php
function StartSearch($start, $sentence)
{
    $data = explode(" ", $sentence);
    $flag = false;
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($data as $val)
    {
        for($i = 0, $j = 0;$i < strlen($val), $j < strlen($start);$i++)
        {
            if ($i == 0 && $val{$i} != $start{$j})
                break;

            if ($flag && $val{$i} != $start{$j})
                break;

            if ($val{$i} == $start{$j})
            {
                $flag = true;
                $j++;
            }
        }

        if ($j == strlen($start))
        {
            $ret[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

print_r(StartSearch("th", $str));

?>
```